# Möbius transformation image

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation

Let $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{z+d}$, when $d\in\mathbb{R}$, $d\not=0$ $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ and $f$ is not constant.
I want to find the image of the real and imaginary axes under $f$. I've found that the image of the real axis is $\{z:z=\frac{a+b}{1+d}+\frac{ad-b}{d(1+d)}u,u\in\mathbb{R}\}$. The pole of f is not on the imaginary axis therefore his image is a circle. From the angle preservation principle the diameter of the circle is on the image of the real axis. I would like a hint.

Comment: The intersections of the real and the imaginary axis (their respective closures in the Riemann sphere) are $0$ and $\infty$. These two are mapped to $\frac{b}{d}$ and $a$ respectively.

Comment: How can I use that?

Comment: a) Since $-d \mapsto \infty$, the image of the real axis is the straight line through these two points. b) a circle whose midpoint lies on a given straight line intersects that line in two points, hence its midpoint is the midpoint of the two intersections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Möbius transformation goes from the $z$-plane to the $w$-plane, where

$$w = \frac{az+b}{z+d}$$

You need to rearrange this equation to make $z$ the subject. Let's say you have
$$z=\frac{pw+q}{rw+s}$$

An equation for the imaginary axis in the $z$-plane is $|z-1|=|z+1|$. (The imaginary axis is the perpendicular bisector of the chord joining $-1$ and $1$.) This equation then becomes
$$\left|\frac{pw+q}{rw+s}-1\right| = \left|\frac{pw+q}{rw+s}+1\right|$$
The solution set of this equation is something in the $w$-plane. It is the image of the imaginary axis.
Make the substitution $w=u+\mathrm{i}v$, apply the definition of modulus, simplify, complete the square on $u$ and $v$ and then read off the answer. See my example below:

**Example**

Consider the Mobius transformation from the $z$-plane to the $w$-plane where

$$w=\frac{z+1}{z+2} \implies z=\frac{1-2w}{w-1}$$

Now we substitute this expression for $z$ into $|z-1|=|z+1|$ and then substitute $w=u+\mathrm{i}v$
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
|z-1| &=& |z+1| \\ \\
\left|\frac{1-2w}{w-1}-1\right| &=& \left|\frac{1-2w}{w-1}+1\right| \\ \\
\left|\frac{2-3w}{w-1}\right| &=& \left|\frac{-w}{w-1}\right| \\ \\
\frac{|2-3w|}{|w-1|} &=& \frac{|-w|}{|w-1|} \\ \\
|3w-2| &=& |w| \\ \\
|(3u-2)+3\mathrm{i}v| &=& |u+\mathrm{i}v| \\ \\
(3u-2)^2 + 9v^2 &=& u^2 + v^2 \\ \\
9u^2 - 12u + 4 + 9v^2 &=& u^2 + v^2 \\ \\
8u^2 - 12u +8v^2 + 4 &=& 0 \\ \\
8\left(u-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2+8v^2 &=& \frac{1}{2} \\ \\
\left(u-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2+v^2 &=& \frac{1}{16}
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Finally, we see that the image of the imaginary axis is a circle, centre $w=\frac{3}{4}$ with radius $\frac{1}{4}$.